# turning live into on in jquery doesnt work

Tags: jquery

i had this code

```
$(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
    if ($('#txtBuscador').val() == '') {
        GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    } else {
        GetCustomersBuscar(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    }
});
```

and i replace it for this

```
$(document).on("click", ".Pager.page", function () {
    if ($('#txtBuscador').val() == '' ) {
        GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    } else { 
        GetCustomersBuscar(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
    }
});
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work , the elements `.Pager.Page` are created dynamically.

```html
<div class="Pager">
  <span>1</span>
  <a style="cursor:pointer" class="page" page="2">2</a>
  <a style="cursor:pointer" class="page" page="3">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `.page` a child element of `.Pager` ? Appear to be two different selectors ?,  at `.live`  `$(".Pager .page")`  ; at `.on` `".Pager.page"` ?

Comment: yes .page is a child of .pager  i will update the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting `".Pager .page"` for `".Pager.page"`

```js
function GetCustomers(page) {
  console.log("GetCustomers", page)
}

function GetCustomersBuscar(page) {
  console.log("GetCustomersBuscar", page)
}

$(document).on("click", ".Pager .page", function () {
    if ($("#txtBuscador").val() == "" ) {
        GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr("page")));
    } else { 
        GetCustomersBuscar(parseInt($(this).attr("page")));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="Pager">
  <div class="page" page="123">click</div>
</div>
<input id="txtBuscador" type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this instead:

```
$('.Pager').on('click', '.page', function() {
  if ($('#txtBuscador').val() == '' ) {
    GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
  } else { 
    GetCustomersBuscar(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
  }
});
```